# Vue integration with Spring MVC using maven enterprise

Tags: spring-mvc, vuejs2, maven-ear-plugin

What is the recommended way to integrate vue with spring mvc? Should I use webpack or other modularization for vue? If yes, how can I do this effectively? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of webjars vue . Please find below links

https://github.com/webjars/vue

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/vue/0.11.0

Tutorial :
https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/03/utilizing-webjars-in-spring-boot